# Prevent redirect and return the json result in a div MVC/C#/Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

This is my function below, I would like some help to figure out how can i prevent redirect after this function has been called and return my json result in the same page in a div called "resultMessage".

```
function PdfHeaderAndFooterManager() {
 $('#formPdfImages').submit(function(event) {
         $.post("@(Url.Action("PdfHeaderAndFooterManager", "Dashboard"))", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $("#resultMessage").text(data.message);
            } else {
                $("resultMessage").text(data.message);
            }

        });
    });
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#formPdfImages').submit(function(event) {
         //event.preventDefault(); // prevent the page reload
         $.post("@(Url.Action("PdfHeaderAndFooterManager", "Dashboard"))", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $("#resultMessage").text(data.message);
            } else {
                $("resultMessage").text(data.message);
            }
           return false;
        });
    });
```